# How can I disable network search only when a specific program is running?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

[Windows 10] Let's say I have a shortcut for a steam a game, *CS:GO* and two command lines written in Notepad, executable as a Batch file.

```
1.   netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Wi-Fi"
2.   netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface="Wi-Fi"
```

These enable and disable, respectively, the constant wireless network searching that the wireless card imposes. What can be done so that, when I click on the *CS:GO* program shortcut, the second line of command runs and when I exit the application the first line of command runs? (In other words, *title*)

FYI Stopping the wireless card from searching nearby networks allows for a slightly better ping in online games and reduces lag spikes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write you two answers. This answers your question, but I think it is a workaround, so I posted another answer with what I think answers your actual problem.

## Answer

Steam allows you to add custom games to steam. A custom game is basically any program or script located on your harddrive. With this in mind, you can create a .cmd file that executes your command, then launches the game. Once the game is exited, the script continues and you can turn it on again.

Lets assume your CS:Go is located at: `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\Common\Counter Strike Go`

You can place the script anywhere, but lets put it in the same folder so you know what it is for.

You can name the script anything, but lets call it `launcher.cmd`

Your script would look something like this:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\Common\Counter Strike Go"

start "" /wait netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface="Wi-Fi"
start "" /wait csgo.exe 
netsh "" wlan set autoconfig enabled=yes interface="Wi-Fi"
```

Keep in mind, that with this option, during the gaming a commandwindow will remain open. This is normal behavior.

Now, in steam, open your library. At the bottom right, choose <kbd>add a game...</kbd> , Add a non-steam game. Now browse to the launcher.cmd file. Once added, you can rename it to anything, from Counter Strike: Go to Half-Life 3 (if you want to prank your friends)

Your friends will see: Playing non-steam game: Counter Strike: Go which is funny by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Run the second command. Then launch the game with a start /wait "command for game".

Then run the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I will write you two answers. The other answer will be the answer to this specific question. This answer however will be the answer to your problem that you're trying to work around.

When you have both WiFi and LAN enabled, Windows will keep using one interface. Although most of the time this is your LAN interface, it is possible that the WiFi interface got set with a higher priority and thus, everything goes through the WiFi.

To change the priority is easy though.

## How to do it in Windows 8.1 and earlier

From the systemtray where you find your wifi network and lan network icon, right-click the icon and select *Open Network and Sharing center*

Go to *Change adapter settings* located on the left.

Now, on your keyboard, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> once, to show the menu. Go to the menu *Advanced*, followed by *Advanced Settings*.

You see both your LAN and WiFi connections listed. If WiFi is at the top, the priority is set to use your WiFi first. Click the WiFi connection, and use the arrow buttons on the right to move it down (or select the LAN and move it to the top)

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> and you're done. No need to reboot, changes are instantly, but any open connection will keep using that interface until reconnected.

EDIT: the above works up-to windows 8.1, and apparently was changed in Windows 10.

In order to change it in windows 10, powershell is needed.

## How to do it in Windows 10

With Windows 10, you may not see an ‘Adapters and Bindings’ dialog box. Even if you get the ‘Adapters and Bindings’ dialog box, when you make adjustments to the binding order and save, and you re-open the Adapters and Bindings dialog box, you will notice that your changes do not persist.

**Why this change?**

There are no longer any components that utilize the binding order. The only known component that used the binding order was DNS ordering. By default, Windows uses the Route Metric + Interface Metric to determine which route has the highest priority by choosing the route with the lowest value.

What if you want to change the priority of a specific network card?

Click Start
Launch Windows PowerShell typing powershell
When the `Windows PowerShell / Desktop app` displays on the top of the list, press Enter
Type the following command in the window and press Enter
`netstat –rn`
You will now see “Interface List” in the results as shown below:

Output:

```
================================================================
Interface List
21…14 8a 7f 0f ee 21 ……Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
8… 14 8a 7f 0f ee 20……Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
23…f4 b7 e2 cc 61 30 ……Bluetooth PAN HelpText
1………………………Software Loopback Interface 1
30…00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
5…00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter #2
49…00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft IP-HTTPS Platform Adapter
================================================================
```

The first number in each row represent the priority of that network aka interface metrics.

Always remember, the lower the number the higher is the priority.

Warning: You may not want to change the default priority order unless you see some real problem with how Windows is prioritizing the network interface cards.

If you are using multiple NICs and you need to increase the priority a specific NIC has over others, use Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric to define the weight for the interface.

For Example: Set-NetIPInterface –InterfaceIndex “xx”–InterfaceMetric “xxx”

For more information on Set-NetIPInterface cmdlet, click on the below web link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826125(v=wps.630).aspx

Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/08/14/adjusting-the-network-protocol-bindings-in-windows-10/

So if you see the WiFi has a higher priority than your LAN, consider changing its priority.